# How does the search algorithm work with objects in a java collection such as HashSet?

Tags: java, hashtable, hashset

The question really is regarding objects that change dynamically in a collection. Does the "contains" method go and compare each of the object individually every time or does it do something clever?

If you have 10000 entries in a collection, I would have expected it to work a bit more cleverly but not sure. Or if not is there a way to optimise it by adding a hook that would tell the collection object to update hashcodes for the objects that have changed??

Additional Question:

Thanks for answers below... Can I also ask what happens in case of ArrayList? I could not find anything in the documentation that says not to put mutable objects in ArrayList. Does that mean the search algorithm simply goes and compares against hashcode of each object??

Comment: Objects in a HashSet must not change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is — no, nothing clever happens. If you expect an object's state to change in a way that affects its `hashCode()` and `equals(...)` behavior, then you **must not** store it in a `HashSet`, nor any other `Set`. To quote from http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html:

> Note: Great care must be exercised if mutable objects are used as set elements. The behavior of a set is not specified if the value of an object is changed in a manner that affects `equals` comparisons while the object is an element in the set. A special case of this prohibition is that it is not permissible for a set to contain itself as an element.

Comment: Thanks that answers my question 1+. Cheers

Answer (score 5):

They hash the object and look it up by its hash code. If it is there, it will compare the objects themselves. This is because two or more objects that have the same hash might not be the same object.

Since Java's hash collections use buckets (chaining), they have to look at all the objects in the bucket. These objects are kept in a linked list (not `java.util.LinkedList`, but a custom list)

This is generally very efficient, and the `HashSet.contains()` method is [amortized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amortized_analysis) O(1) (constant time).

---

[Java's docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) have an answer to the second part of your question:

> Note: Great care must be exercised if mutable objects are used as set elements. **The behavior of a set is not specified if the value of an object is changed** in a manner that affects equals comparisons while the object is an element in the set. A special case of this prohibition is that it is not permissible for a set to contain itself as an element.

Comment: What happens that objects (internal variables) that may change. Or the collection knows the changed hash of the object. I thought they use some sort of sorted hash so objects can be found quicker.... Else it will have to go through all the objects checking for the hash right??

Comment: From the JavaDoc:
"Note: great care must be exercised if mutable objects are used as map keys. The behavior of a map is not specified if the value of an object is changed in a manner that affects equals comparisons while the object is a key in the map. A special case of this prohibition is that it is not permissible for a map to contain itself as a key. While it is permissible for a map to contain itself as a value, extreme caution is advised: the equals and hashCode methods are no longer well defined on such a map.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html

Comment: Thanks for this clarification. I accept Ruakh's answer though as he pointed it first.. :) 1+ for the answer.

Comment: Note that "look at all the objects" doesn't mean "call equals on all the objects" - it remembers the hash code, so it only needs to do that cheap comparison on each element in the bucket, and the potentially-expensive equality check on elements which really have a matching hash code.

Comment: @NullUserExceptionఠ_ఠ: No - otherwise you'd have a potentially huge table. Have a look at the implementation of `HashMap` for example - you can end up with several objects with *congruent* hash codes (mod table length). It's quick to iterate over those to only check the ones with the exact same hash codes though. If you didn't know about that, it's not clear what you mean by "Since Java's hash collections use buckets [...]" - *any* hash-based implementation would have to allow for multiple elements with the same hash code.

Comment: @JonSkeet You are right; that was some major brain malfunction on my part.

Answer (score 3):

A `HashSet` computes the [*hash code*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) of an element when it's added to the set. It stores this in a way which makes it very efficient to find all elements with the same hash code.

Then when you call `contains()`, it simply has to compute the hash code of the value you're *looking* for, and find all elements in the set with the same hash code. There may be multiple elements as hash codes aren't unique, but there are likely to be far fewer elements with matching hash codes than there are elements within the set itself. Each matching element is then checked with `equals` until either a match is found or we've run out of candidates.

EDIT: To answer the second part, which somehow I'd missed on first reading, you won't be able to find the element again. You *mustn't* change an element used as a key in a hash table or an element in a hash set in any equality-affecting manner, or you will basically break things.

Comment: What happens when the object content changes after its been added to a collection? Then the hashcode of the object has changed. How does the collection know of the new updated value?

Comment: @SidMalani: It doesn't, and you won't be able to find that. It's documented *not* to work in that case.

Answer (score 0):

A `HashSet` uses a `HashMap` under the hood. Therefore, the `contains` operation uses the `hashCode()` method in the object to check if it's present in the hash table implemented by `HashMap`.